# Gson losing data when reconstructing deserializing object

Tags: java, android, gson

I don't really know how to word the title of this question, so if anyone has a better title please suggest it. I am trying to encode/decode an ArrayList of `Sessions`s and each session has an ArrayList of `Shot`s. The problem I am having is that when I try to encode the list of Sessions, Gson doesn't dig into the array of Shots for each session and encode the ArrayList of shots, but just leaves an empty array:

```
[  
   {  
      "ANGLE":71.356865,
      "DATE":"2015-11-25-11-02",
      "KEY":62,
      "SHOTS":[  

      ]
   },
   {  
      "ANGLE":75.26292,
      "DATE":"2015-11-25-11-02",
      "KEY":63,
      "SHOTS":[  

      ]
   }
]
```

Sessions Class

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
public class Session {
    @SerializedName("SHOTS") @Expose
    public ArrayList<Shot> shots;
    @SerializedName("SCORE") @Expose
    public float averageScore;
    @SerializedName("DATE") @Expose
    public String date;
    @SerializedName("KEY") @Expose
    public int pk;
    ...
}
```

Shots class

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
public class Shot {
    public String identifier;
    @SerializedName("SCORE") @Expose
    public double score;
    @SerializedName("TYPE") @Expose
    public int problem;
    @SerializedName("PROBLEM_STRING") @Expose
    public String problemString;
    ...
}
```

Building the json string:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();
String json = gson.toJson(sessions);
```

### update

After looking into this more, data is being lossed when I am rebuilding the object and not when I am serializing it. This is the code I am using to deserialize it:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Session>>(){}.getType();
sessions = gson.fromJson(sessionsString, type);
```

### update

After even more digging, **my data loss is not related to the encoding/deconging of Gson**. I would like to apologize to Google for blaming them. My problem seems to be related to AsyncTask and I have reposted it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33929251/java-calling-asynctask-doinbackground-is-editing-random-class-attributes).

Answer (score 0):

First are you sure of the name ?
Second the only array I see is the score

```
 "SCORE":[  

  ]
```

please recheck the json object or update it with actual data

Comment: I updated it. That was a copy and paste error to stack overflow. It should be "SHOTS":[] and not "SCORE":[].